# Правильно ли обособлен деепричастный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

Из современной литературы:

*— Станция «Беговая». Будьте осторожны при выходе из последней двери последнего вагона…*

*Г., собиравшийся вслед за Л. выйти именно из последней двери, насмерть перепугался и, **на всякий случай раздумав вообще пользоваться дверьми**, вылез через приоткрытое окно вагона, шлепнувшись у ее ног.*

Сомнения такие:

1. Правильно ли обособлен деепричастный оборот?
2. Предложение перегружено запятыми. Можно ли автору предложить другое (по структуре и пунктуации) оформление?

Comment: Оборот выделен жирным, чтобы его не отнесли к причастным?

Comment: Оборот выделен в качестве структуры, правильность оформления которой вызывает сомнение

Comment: Выделенное не автором текста требует соответствующей отсылки к сноске или пояснения в скобках. Иначе цитата считается искажённой. Внешние знаки препинания выделять не принято.

Comment: Хорошо, не буду больше выделять (если вообще буду еще задавать вопросы). И если поправите, то тоже не буду возражать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> — Станция «Беговая». Будьте осторожны при выходе из последней двери последнего вагона…
> Грзенк, собиравшийся вслед за Лирдой выйти именно из последней двери, насмерть перепугался **и, на всякий случай раздумав вообще пользоваться дверьми, вылез через приоткрытое окно вагона,** шлепнувшись у ног дочери.
> [Д. Емец. Великое Нечто](https://books.google.ee/books?id=iX_PAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT151&lpg=PT151&dq=%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%C2%AB%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%C2%BB.%20%D0%91%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=-nCqDJmh3_&sig=ACfU3U2L-HHd7PpitHqV_4s5oV-XnlpDFg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjypOWi79zwAhVv-yoKHeB7BYcQ6AEwDnoECBwQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%C2%AB%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%C2%BB.%20%D0%91%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0&f=false)

Да, действий в предложении много: собрался выйти, перепугался, раздумал пользоваться, вылез, шлепнулся.
А пунктуация, связанная с деепричастным оборотом, зависит от того, к какому из действий автор относит устойчивое сочетание [на всякий случай](http://endic.ru/phrase/Na-vsjaki-slucha-785.html) (в значении наречия; допуская возможность чего-либо неожиданного, неопределенного).

А. *На всякий случай раздумал* [передумал] *пользоваться*
Запятые стоят правильно.
Примеры такого использования есть:
*Хотел я ему похвастаться, что у меня сегодня второй день рождения, но **на всякий случай передумал**, решив лишний раз не дёргать судьбу за хвост* (М. Белозеров); *Портифон подумал малость и **на всякий случай передумал** проклинать* (А. Силецкий).

Б. *На всякий случай вылез*
Пунктуация должна быть такой:
*...насмерть перепугался и на всякий случай, **раздумав вообще пользоваться дверьми,** вылез через приоткрытое окно...*
И такие примеры есть:
*Тот приоткрыл один глаз, заметил, что вся компания как-то странно на него смотрит, и **на всякий случай вылез** из будки* (Е. Лазаренко); *Лёха **на всякий случай вылез** своей огромной, крепкой башкой в окошко кабины...* (З. Прилепин).

А предложение понятное, динамичное, — я бы ничего не стала менять (правда, предпочла бы смысловой вариант Б).

Comment: Спасибо, Римма, за ответ. Что же вы меня «разоблачаете», ведь люди подумают, что я ничего, кроме фантастики, не читаю и сделают соответствующие выводы (а некоторые, наверное,  это уже давно сделали) :)  (1) Я думаю, что наречие в данном случае лучше отнести к сочетанию  «на всякий случай вылез из окна», чем «на всякий случай раздумал  пользоваться дверьми», как-то очень длинно получается.  (2) Я бы всё-таки разделила  предложение на две части тире, так бы и динамика лучше улавливалась.

Comment: Ну-у... Коли так, я могу изничтожить... Правда, я всегда предпочитаю ссылку иметь, потому что иногда многое зависит от сопутствующего контекста. Здесь же оказалось, что такого влияния окружения нет.

Comment: Римма. это же шутка, зря вы все понимаете дословно.  Я имела в виду наших новых участников, у которых обо мне вполне определенное мнение. Конечно, пусть остается информация.

Comment: "Дык" и я шутейно. Рада, что в этом вопросе мы смотрим почти в одном направлении.